# How would I play songs or make a splash screen for my cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

How would I play songs or make a splash screen for my cocoa app? I know it's a simple question but I am a complete noob when it comes to cocoa.

Answer (score 4):

You want to create an application delegate class and implement the `-applicationWillFinishLaunching` and `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` methods to display/hide your splash screen or start/stop your audio. You can connect an instance of this class as the application's delegate in Interface Builder in the project's `MainMenu.xib`.

Keep in mind that it's generally considered bad form to have to display a splash/load screen in Mac apps. If your app can start instantly and lazily load resources or load them in a background thread, it provides a much nicer experience for your users.

Answer (score 2):

Barry is right, you have to get rid of this idea to use splash screens.. it's mainly a M$ Windows concept and it is kind of frustrating for the user to wait for the app to load itself, and I bet you won't load a thing and you just want to show a splash screen so you can feel important, but I'm telling you: apps with "marketing-only" splash screens are trash right from the beginning, because the user waits for absolutely nothing to load, and he/she will immediatelly get sick of seeing it every single time the app starts..

Now, about the songs.. I'll help you on this one, but I'm telling you again: it's useless, can't see the usefullness in having a sound play on every startup... so putting sound and a splash screen to your app startup will scare most users away, and your app won't made it!

So, to load a song you use the NSSound class like this:

```
NSSound *s = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:songPath byReference:YES];
```

and then you can control it with the following methods:

```
[s play]
[s pause]
[s resume]
[s stop]
```